# using a hash other than sha1 for OAEP with OpenSSL / CLI

Tags: rsa, openssl

The [rsautl OpenSSL utility](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/rsautl.html) does not appear to have a setting wherein the hash for OAEP can be changed. My testing suggests that it just defaults to sha1 and that's it.

My question is...  is there a way to change the hash?

The command I used to test it out:

```
openssl rsautl -inkey publickey.txt -encrypt -oaep -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.txt
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`rsautl` which is ancient, no. [`pkeyutl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkeyutl.html) which was supposed to supersede `rsautl` in 2010, yes. `-pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:name` or `rsa_mgf1_md:name` where `name` is a hash [as in your Q on PSS](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31430/setting-the-mgf-hash-to-a-different-value-other-than-the-regular-hash-with-opens).

Note for `pkeyutl` (edit) before 1.1.0 the **order of options matters**; you must do `-encrypt` then `-inkey rsaprivate` *then* `-pkeyopt` (not currently documented AFAICS, though the analogous cases in `genpkey` are) and you need to do `rsa_padding_mode:oaep` before `rsa_{oaep,mgf1}_md:hash` .

Same possible issue with FIPS mode.

Comment: I was trying this just now (maybe I tried it earlier too idk) and I had to do `-pkeyopt` before each option. eg. `openssl pkeyutl -in ciphertext.txt -decrypt -inkey test.pem -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha1`. So in that case I needed to do it once for each option - not once globally.

Comment: @neubert: yes you need `-pkeyopt` for each key-option; I thought that part was clear from the manpage and didn't repeat it. But the requirements on order were (and are) not all documented AFAICS, and such requirements are unusual for `openssl`, so I called them out.

Comment: The ordering doesn't appear to matter with OpenSSL 1.1.0f, but I couldn't find these options documented. Although `-pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256` works, it is not mentioned on `man pkeyutl`.

Comment: @starfry: (don't know why I wasn't notified at the time) yes, 1.1.0, released 8 months after I wrote this answer, completely reimplemented option handling for all commandline operations; edited for anyone else who comes along. It's `rsa_mgf1_md` which applies to both OAEP _and_ PSS -- and is documented in 1.1.1 which turnaboutly postdates your comment :-)